# MS Access front end see no linked tabled from SQL backend?

Tags: ms-access

I created an Access database (back end) and linked lots of tables to my SQL Server.

I created a second Access database (front end) and when I try to link to the linked sql tables from the first (back end) database, the list shows up empty - no linked table.

Can't I have a back end Access db with linked SQL tables and then access them from a front end Access database (as linked)?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No.

From your second database, you will have to link the tables you need from SQL Server.